# Is it possible to cache a script when data is passed through it via a uri?

Tags: php, api, caching

I was wondering if it is possible to cache some data that is passed to the php script via the URI using PHP's APC.

If it is possible, then I want to know if using APC is the best caching solution for my website.

My website basically probes various APIs from the internet such as YouTube, and Echonest to get data on musicians. At the moment when a user clicks on an artist on my website the artist's data is freshly loaded from the various APIs. There is a long list of artists on the website, and so is caching them all a good idea? Currently my site is really slow because I am probing the APIs constantly for every time a user clicks on a new artist.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you require absolute real time and sync to your various data providers, caching is generally a very good idea to speed up your site indeed.

APC does opcode caching, and can be used for data caching as well, so it is suitable for caching api responses and data from your providers (see APC's api here http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.apc.php)

APC however runs per web server, so if you have a HA setup with multiple web servers, and you require all your web servers to be in sync with regards to cache, then you might want to take a look at memcache/redis for centralized caching instead.

Note that whether you need cross-server sync or not is completely your decision and dependant on the nature of your app; there is no right and wrong answer for this. FYI: synchronized cache incur a network io cost that APC does not have.

In any case, whether using APC or memcache/redis, caching per URI patterns, or from query string parameters is perfectly fine. These cache works based with key/values, so it's up to you to devise a naming convention system for your keys, to store the relevant pieces of data. For example:

```
$key = sprintf("%s/%s/%s/%s", $provider_name, $api_endpoint, $param1, $param2);
apc_add($key, $the_data, 300); // cache for 5mns
```